# How to transform syscall.Handle to net.Conn on windows?

Tags: windows, go

Consider the following:

```
if fd, err = syscall.Socket(family, syscall.SOCK_STREAM, syscall.IPPROTO_TCP); err != nil {
    return
}

// do something on fd like bind ...

if err = os.NewSyscallError("connect", syscall.Connect(fd, sockaddr)); err != nil {
    syscall.Close(fd)
    return
}

f := os.NewFile(uintptr(fd), "socket")
conn, err = net.FileConn(f)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    f.Close()
    syscall.Close(fd)
}
```

result: `file file+net socket: not supported by windows`

Is there any way to transfrom the `syscall.Handle` to a `net.Conn` on Windows ?

I use Windows 10 and go version 1.10.3 windows/amd64

Comment: I'm afraid you cannot as you actually picked a correct way of doing that but the `net.FileConn` is indeed explicitly documented as being not supported on Windows: «On NaCl and Windows, the `FileConn`, `FileListener` and `FilePacketConn` functions are not implemented.».

Comment: One way to tackle this I might think of is that since, I think, v1.10, access to any _pollable_ file descriptor/handle is now handled via the netpoller, so you might do two things: 1) write your custom type around your handle which would implement `net.Conn` (remember it's merely an interface); 2) make sure the handles your syscall returns are "pollable" as far as the Go runtime is concerned. Ensuring this might require additional trickery so it's better to come up with a more concrete question on [the mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/golang-nuts).